# PHP exec, running shell command problems (using archlinux)

Tags: php, apache, shell, exec, archlinux

I am using Archlinux and I want to run the following script (the last line actually):

```
<?php
var_dump(get_current_user());
var_dump(exec("whoami"));
var_dump(exec("sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value"));
```

The script has the following permissions (I have tried with and without sudo in the last line)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http http  126 Nov 17 17:24 turn_on.php
```

and `http` was added to `\etc\sudoers` with **ALL** permissions

```
http ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

The result of opening the `turn_on.php` script in a browser is:

```
string(4) "http" string(4) "http" string(0) ""
```

The script does not do what it should (last line) and the in the apache log, every time I reload the browser I get:

```
sh: /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value: Permission denied
```

This is my first test to deal with what I want to do, I'm thinking in making something more "PHP web service API-style". Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Cheers.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the permissions of /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value as that is what is producing the permissions error.

Also, try using sudo from command line to imitate the script's functionality:

```
sudo -u http echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio44/value
```

If this fails then you just need to tinker with your permissions until it works correctly, then try again from browser.

If the above works but it still fails in the browser then it's probable that the execution of your script is not actually using the http user.